# Using content script to inject audio

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script which reads data and using google tts service gets the output audio.
The problem concerns injecting script through extension

When i inject the audio element through javascript I see the right url being called and audio element appended . But it doesnt play . I have set autoplay attribute .

Snippet I am using

```
    var url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=' + encoded;
console.log(url);
var audio = new Audio();
audio.setAttribute('src',url);
audio.setAttribute('autoplay');
var t = document.getElementById('doc');
if(t.appendChild(audio)){
    console.log('appended');
}
```

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/detail/dhfpnmpbgjadmhggjeajdfmkcclckeim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot load audio through content script . This can however be achieved using background page .

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't have any luck with Mr. Mansour's `load` and `play` recommendation. I think the issue here is that you both got half of it right: a) set `autoplay` to `true`, and b) just do it in the background page.

For example, I got this background page to run just fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Background";
      var audio = new Audio(url);
      audio.autoplay = true;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note also that I never appended the element to the document; if you have no luck there you can always tack on an `appendChild` and see if that makes a difference.

Also, I think your original code should work just fine -- even if an element with ID `doc` doesn't exist -- if you throw it in the background page.

**Some more notes**

For some weird reason, "correcting" the ampersand to `&amp;` instead of `&` breaks it for me. Awkward, but just a caution to others.

Also, if you just open the console and paste in the three lines of JavaScript from above, it probably won't work -- unless you're in a special page like the New Tab page, an extension options page, or, you guessed it, an extension background page. I'm not sure why this is so, but Chrome may have restrictions on who can inject audio content and have it play. I don't know why this would be so, or whether it's intentional or unintentional. Just another caveat in working with HTML5, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to append child, and do it from the background page:

```
var audio = new Audio(url);
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

That should work, load it in the JavaScript and it will play.

Comment: Hmm either way its the same . I tried your way but still didnt work .

Comment: The url it logs its proper meaning if i open in new tab it plays sound.

Comment: Did you do it from the background page? I did that locally and it worked. Perhaps you would need to add proper permissions in the manifest since its an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that is not listed here is this one : You could inject your audio in the page and control from the content script.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "script",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://example.com/"
      ],
      "js": [
        "inject.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "audios/*"
  ]
}
```

*Note*: don't forget to include your audios in `web_accessible_resources`.

**inject.js**

```js
const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL('audios/notification-sound.mp3'))
audio.id = 'injected-audio'
document.body.appendChild(audio)
```

**content.js**

```js
function notify () {
  document.querySelector('#injected-audio').play()
}

notify()
```

I think it's clean way, this way you can play your sound whenever you want.